# How to keep screen proces alive after crash

Tags: linux, debian

I want to run proces after crash. Script must be always running. I don't know how to do these.

My code what im running script.

```
cd /var/www/bot
screen -dmS tradebot ./start.sh
```

start.sh file

```
nodejs sell.js
```

Comment: What tools/languages are you using?

Comment: my script is writed in nodejs and im starting like these `nodejs sell.js`

Comment: may be try `nohup` ?

Comment: How about `while true; do nodejs sell.js; done` in your script? Horrible, but does what you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `while true; do nodejs sell.js; done` in your script? Horrible, but does what you asked. – nsilent22